# Excluding libraries/dependencies from ArchUnit?

Tags: junit5, archunit

I'm using ArchUnit 1.0.1 and I have this test class:

```java
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.mycompany", importOptions = {DoNotIncludeTests.class})
public class MyTest {

    @ArchTest
    public static final ArchRule my_test = 
            noClasses()
            .that()
                    .resideInAPackage("com.mycompany.x.."))
            .should()
                    .accessClassesThat()
                    .resideOutsideOfPackage("com.mycompany.x.."))
}
```

Want I want to assert is that no class in "com.mycompany.x" (and it's subpackages) use any other class in the project. For example, it should not be allowed for classes in "com.mycompany.x" to access classes in "com.mycompany.y". However, it's okay for classes in "com.mycompany.x" to use methods/classes from any (external) library/dependency, as long as it's not "com.mycompany" (expect for "com.mycompany.x").

How can I change my test above to take this into account?

Answer (score 0):

ArchUnit provides the conditions `onlyAccessClassesThat()` and `resideOutsideOfPackage(..)`. In your case, you should able to write this rule like this:

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule accesses_of_x = classes()
        .that().resideInAPackage("com.mycompany.x..")
        .should().onlyAccessClassesThat().resideOutsideOfPackage("com.mycompany..")
        .orShould().onlyAccessClassesThat().resideInAPackage("com.mycompany.x..");
```